# problems with another form

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

```
<?php
         error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set( 'display_errors','1');

    if(isset($_POST["signupbtn"])) {
        if ($log_username) {
            /// getting data from submitted form into local variables
            $yt = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['youtubei']);
            $t = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['twitchi']);
            $vt = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['videotypei']);
            $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
            // -------------------------------------------
                if (is_numeric($t[0])) {
                echo 'Twitch Account cannot begin with a number';
                exit();
            } else  { $sqli = "UPDATE profilepage SET youtube='$yt' WHERE username='$log_username'";
                    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
                     $sqli = "UPDATE profilepage SET twitch='$t' WHERE username='$log_username'";
                    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
                     $sqli = "UPDATE profilepage SET videotype='$vt' WHERE username='$log_username'";
                    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
                       echo "Video feeds update"; 

                exit();     
                }
         }
    }

    ?>
    <?php {
    echo('<form action="profile_interface/modules/videofeedform.php" method="POST" name="videoform">');
    echo('<input id="youtubei" value="YouTube Video Key" maxlength="16">');
    echo('<input id="twitchi" value="twrdodge" type="text" maxlength="16">');
    echo('<select id="videotypei"><option value="">Select Display video</option>');
    echo('<option value="yotubekey">YouTube</option>');
    echo('<option value="twitchuser">Twitch</option>');
    echo('</select>');
    echo('<input type="submit" id="signupbtn" name="signupbtn"></form>');
    }
    EXIT();

    ?>
```

First of all I am trying to learn php. I have read a few books and watched a lot of videos (I am still studying).

I am now trying to experiment with forms by updating info on the database. The table is already established during signup and now i would like to update it.

ok so the above code is the form and php to database. This is embedded on a page what has no issues displaying this content and the page is called user.php (users profile page).

Now the thing is every time I fill in the form and submit, it just refreshes the page and when I look at the database nothing is updated. I was wondering if any would be able to point out where I am going wrong with this.

What I have tried:
1) I have tried deleting all the form input (and relevant database code) except one input and it just refreshes.
2) I have tried using `INSERT INTO`

now the `$log_username` isn't an issue as the top script does the checks for that and everything comes back fine so I know it isn't an issue with `$log_username`.

It doesn't bring back any errors at all and the connection to the database is also established through the top `INCLUDE_ONCE` what isn't the issue as it works through out the website.

If anyone could point out where I am going wrong here and possible put the correct code in a reply I will appreciate it very much. Thanks for taking your time in reading this and I look forward to your reply.

Comment: Where are you actually submitting the form? I don't see anything that links the submit button to the form submission. Also - why are you using PHP to `echo()` the HTML? If you just remove the surrounding `<?php` and  `?>` you can just write the HTML

Comment: @Dutchie432 In most browsers, a <button> tag is a submitbutton by default, unless you specify otherwise. Although it is good practice to always specify a type. W3C says: "Always specify the type attribute for the <button> element. Different browsers may use different default types for the <button> element."

Comment: @DickW I can honestly say I've never used a `<button>` tag in my life. I just use CSS to style divs and inputs. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: if I do not echo out the form then I get a 1 put under the form. I am not sure why this happens but it does. It might be down to the fact that you need to have this form activated on the database for it to show. The activation script works fine

Answer (score 1):

First thing first

You need a name for you submit button. You have

```
<button id="signupbtn">
```

I would suggest to make it as

```
<input type="submit" id="signupbtn" name="signupbtn">
```

You are using

```
if(isset($_POST["signupbtn"])) {)
```

so it will not find any POST with the name you specified unless your form has some element with that name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added the update code to the original code. I have tested it and page still refreshes and no database update. Thanks again

Comment: Hmm may be some sql error ? You can verify if the code comes inside the if(isset($_POST["signupbtn"])) {} by doing echo of the form elements.

Comment: if you mean is it like `if(isset($_POST["signupbtn"])) {......CODE HERE.....}` then yes all the code is within the `....CODE HERE....`

Comment: right but you need to use echo those posted data inside that block to see if all the data is coming through and if yes then the next step to check for the query errors

Comment: ok so you want me to establish 3 echos with the {......} I believe I am doing this before i put the variables in place? Will I do this echo 'youtubei' and so on for the other 2? Thank you for your time

Comment: I done the following `echo $yt; echo $t; echo $vt;` after I bring the posted data into variables. I put this directly under where I establish the variables. it doesn't show anything and just refreshes the page

Comment: and also check the mysqli error that will give u more insight about what is happening

Comment: I went to the url of the form directly and these are the errors i get http://gyazo.com/0b63ed875eeb541b5aa969adff9ed8c9

Comment: Hmm check your form code all the element needs some name you only have id. You need to add name as well. <input id="youtubei" value="YouTube Video Key" maxlength="16" name="youtubei"> etc for all the elements including the select also. Otherwise the $_POST["youtubei"] etc will not receive any value in PHP

Comment: I have found my issue. My module is made of different files and because and that is effecting the include once's so I need to sort that out. everything goes to the database when it is in index so thank you for helping me resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

$_POST["signupbtn"] works off of the name attribute not the id one

change all of your id's to names and you shoudl work. Also instead of `<button id="signupbtn">Submit</button>` use `<input type="submit" name="signupbtn" value="Submit" />`

```
echo('<form action="profile_interface/modules/videofeedform.php" method="POST" name="videoform">');
echo('<input name="youtubei" value="YouTube Video Key" maxlength="16">');
echo('<input name="twitchi" value="twrdodge" type="text" maxlength="16">');
echo('<select name="videotypei"><option value="">Select Display video</option>');
echo('<option value="yotubekey">YouTube</option>');
echo('<option value="twitchuser">Twitch</option>');
echo('</select>');
echo('<input type="submit" name="signupbtn" value="Submit" /></form>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated it with a name now and also updated the code in the original post. I am still getting the same issue with no database update and no data being written to the database

Comment: are you getting anything echo'd from your script? if not i would suggest add ing `else { echo 'log_username is false';}` to the 'if($log_username)' statement also something similar to the `if(isset($_POST["signupbtn"]))` statement, that way you can see exactly where your script is failing

Comment: I have tried what you asked me too and doesn't seem to echo anything. here is a image of where I put the code http://gyazo.com/52ec2e5984d48f1de781655073bccdb9  Thanks for your reply and time

Comment: if that isnt printing out anything then the `if(isset($_POST["signupbtn"])) {` condition mush not be being triggered for whatever reason, it may be that you have a name wrong, to check exactly what is being posted to your script you can put `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your file (it might help narrow down the problem)

Comment: This is now solved. It is because I needed to have multiply session checks through out my scrip. I solved it by putting the include folders into each folder that contained the script. Thank you for your time as your comments helped me resolve this issue.

Comment: I know have another issue where the div that contains the start of this module glitches out all other div's below it :(. One problem after another however the module works 100% other then the glitch. The complete code for this module is here also with the glitch problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278441/div-makes-divs-below-it-disappear/21278601?noredirect=1#comment32066932_21278601. Thanks once again for your time.