# div makes div's below it disappear

Tags: php, html, css

ok so basically as soon as I include this into my content `<div id="midmid"><?php include_once ("videob/activate-or-view.php"); ?></div>`it stops all divs underneath it from showing up.

the code above is to a module I have made but the module it self needs 5 files to function and are all interlinked to each other. the module itself works perfect except the div glitch. I do not have any divs in the modules and the only div containing any data for the module is the one that is holding it in the content page.

I have tried bringing as much code to the page as possible but that didn't seem to solve the problem. I believe my problem is having `<?php ?>` within a `div` I have tried a number of methods but none seem to work and I believe it is the fact that I am containing  within a div as these errors are all link to the module and mainly the youtube embed code I actually got from youtube it self[image]

I have scanned the individual files with phpscanner and they all seem to come back fine however when I scan the page where they all come together it seems to bring up errors like they were nothing.

Basically I was wondering if any body knows away around these errors and above all else whether they have the slightest idea why when I add the `include once` between `<?php ?>`it glitches out any `div's` that are placed beneath it.

I am new to php but i am learning quite fast. I am still studying php through books and videos but I can't seem to find the answers i am looking for so if anyone knows how I might be able to solve this problem then I would be appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Where's your `</div>` after the include...

Comment: Post your code, the error seems already found!

Comment: it is the bottom div what is causing the problem

Comment: What do you mean with "all the divs beneath it"? There are no other divs after the include.

Comment: I folded your code using http://jsfiddle.net/ (TydyUp button). Please also post the contents of the <?php include_once( "profile_interface/videob/activate-or-view.php"); ?>. The above code seems OK on first sight.

Comment: ok. I will post all forms

Comment: @Mr Lister this is a .php file it self. This code is also a include once code. This gets included on to the users page.

Comment: I have added all the code linked. If you wish me too I will post the actual user.php code. Thank you for your time and thank you to everyone who has gave me a response

Answer (score 0):

your example shows `<div id="midmid"><?php include_once ("videob/activate-or-view.php"); ?>`

But do you close the div after including the php aswell?

```
<div id="midmid"><?php include_once ("videob/activate-or-view.php"); ?></div>
```

The second problem might be that the included file has ?> php ending tag at the end. Sometimes including php files into another php files will be messed up if the included file has php ending tag.

Comment: yes I do include it. I have posted the code. I am going to correct the original post.

Comment: Just try to remove the ?> tag from included php files. Leave the ?> ending tag only to the php file that is not included into any other php files.

Comment: It didn't work :( I even tried removing tags from different places and so on but came back with errors :(. Thanks for the response tho

Comment: I have just tried adding the div's to the includes instead of on the content code and still the same issue :(

Comment: isn't there a way to see it live? Is any parts of it uploaded yet so I could inspect the elements?

Comment: http://192.254.250.166/~twrdodge/user.php?u=twrdodge that will take you to a test users page

Comment: Could the CSS file make it not show up if I have not positioned the divs correct in the file? I am really stumped with this as the php seems to be fine and doesn't seem to miss any tags at all